# How to retract rules from pyDataLog

Tags: python, logic-programming, pydatalog

I'm implementing a FOIL-like algorithm in which I want to efficiently try different hypotheses (i.e., clauses) while I keep the rest of data untouched. I was wondering how without using clear() function, I could retract a rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
load("-(head <= body)")
```